# Align numpy array according to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `a` containing arbitrary integer numbers, and I have another array `b`, (it is always a subset of  `a`, but the order of numbers in `b` is different than `a`.  I want to align the elements of `b` in the order it appears in `a`.

```
a = np.array([4,2,6,5,8,7,10,12]);
b = np.array([10,6,2,12]),
```

I want `b` to be align as [2,6,10,12].  How can I do it in numpy efficiently ?

Comment: Could there be duplicate elements in `a`?

Comment: no, there can not be duplicate elements in `a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** One approach with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), assuming no duplicates in `a` -

```
a[np.in1d(a,b)]
```

Better sample case with elements in `a` disturbed such that its not sorted for the common elements to present a variety case -

```
In [103]: a
Out[103]: array([ 4, 12,  6,  5,  8,  7, 10,  2])

In [104]: b
Out[104]: array([10,  6,  2, 12])

In [105]: a[np.in1d(a,b)]
Out[105]: array([12,  6, 10,  2])
```

---

**Approach #2 :** One approach with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
sidx = a.argsort()
out = a[np.sort(sidx[np.searchsorted(a,b,sorter=sidx)])]
```

Comment: You might add a comment for `in1d` that this assumes there are no duplicates in `a` and `b`, while `#2` works if there are duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, it requires no duplicates in either, because duplicates in `a` will be duplicated (no matter how often it's present in `b`) in the result and duplicates in `b` are ignored.

Comment: @MSeifert Well if there are no duplicates in `a` and given that `b` is  a subset of `a` automatiically guarantees that `b` won't have any duplicates either. If I understood your question?

Comment: I'm just nitpicking :-) You're probably right and for this question it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MSeifert I got that :) Well if there are dups, the question has to be re-stated anyway as then we need to decide which ones to select from `a` and from `b` for deciding the order for those dups.