# Numpy: I need to pigeonhole (sort) an array according to another, when both are unsorted and of different sizes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

I have a list called `transactions`. The elements of the list are dictionaries. Each dictionary contains two numpy arrays: an `index_arr` and an `object_arr`.

The goal is to go through the list and sort all the `index_arr` and `object_arr` so that when we compare two transactions, the order is the same so comparison can be done easily.

The problem is that given two arbitrary transactions `A` and `B`, `A["index_arr"]` does not contain all the elements found in `B["index_arr"]`. So what I want to do is copy `index_arr` and `object_arr` to two new arrays with the size of the maximum number of elements. Then if `A` is missing some elements from `B`, I just leave the corresponding space in the new array empty.

---

So this is pretty complicated and the question is, how do I do this as efficiently as possible in terms of processing speed (memory is cheaper, more readily available).

The approach I can come up with is as follows:

1. Go through the list of transactions and find the maximum number of elements in any given `index_arr`. Let's call this transaction `k`.
2. For each other transaction `j`, create empty numpy arrays for `index_arr` and `object_arr` of the maximum size.
3. For each element of `index_arr` and `object_arr` of transaction `j` copy it to the new empty array in the same location as it is in transaction `k`. And leave the missing elements as null.

This approach works, but is slow. I am asking if there is a more clever way to do this, maybe using some numpy functionality that I am not aware of? I could sort transaction `k` to speed up the look up in step 3. But I think even then it is still very slow. The copying of the array elements one by one is very slow. Is there a better approach?

EDIT: I will expand on the exact problem here. The data structure is as follows:

```
transactions = [dic0, dic1, ..., dic200]
index_arr = np.array([-9, 3, 53, -3, -89])
object_arr = np.array([0.1, 0.3, 0.4, -0.1, 0.5])

dic0 = {
   "index_arr" : index_arr
   "object_arr" : object_arr
}
```

Now my brute force solution is:

First we find out the maximum number of elements `max_e` and the index of the transaction in which they occur `max_e_t`:

```
max_e = -1
max_e_t = -1
k = 0
for t in transactions:
   s = t["index_arr"].size
   if s > max_e:
      max_e = s
      max_e_t = k
   j += 1
```

Then we create new copies of all the other transactions and sort them accordingly:

```
for t in transactions:
   new_index_arr = np.empty(max_e, dtype=int64)
   new_object_arr = np.empty(max_e, dtype=float64)
   n = 0
   for i in t["index_arr"]:
      idx = np.where(transactions[max_e_t]["index_arr"]==i)[0][0]
      new_index_arr[idx] = i
      new_object_arr[idx] = t["object_arr"][n] 
      n += 1
   t["index_arr"] = new_index_arr
   t["object_arr"] = new_object_arr
```

Comment: Can you please provide a representative example? It is hard to provide a faster solution when we know neither the current solution nor what data to work with.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] so we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: *"The problem is that given two arbitrary transactions A and B, A["index_arr"] does not contain all the elements found in B["index_arr"]. So what I want to do is copy index_arr and object_arr to two new arrays with the size of the maximum number of elements. Then if A is missing some elements from B, I just leave the corresponding space in the new array empty."* Are you sure that you can't have a situation where elements are missing from both A and B? For instance, `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `B = [1, 2, 3, 5]`. Then A is missing 5 and B is missing 4.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I added code now

Comment: @Joooeey I added code now

Comment: @Stef yes that is possible, but not a problem because I sort against the largest transaction, the largest transaction is guranteed to contain all elements that appear in all other transactions.

Comment: Related question: [Numpy: How to best align two sorted arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275381/numpy-how-to-best-align-two-sorted-arrays)

Comment: Also: [Align numpy array according to another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923906/align-numpy-array-according-to-another-array)

Comment: I don't think your edits are making the question clearer. You're diluting your actual question in a ton of context that's not really relevant for the problem. For example, is it really important that you have a list of dictionaries `{ "index_arr" : ..., "object_arr" : ...}`? From what I understand of your question, the important point is simply "I have a list of sorted numpy arrays, where every array is a subsequence of the longest array. I want to align all those arrays by adding null values in smaller arrays."

Comment: That's not an [mcve]. Already the first line is something I can't run. Please do take the time to go through the link. And another point that's not mentioned in there: It would help if you show us what the expected output is.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple algorithm to align a smaller sorted array with a larger sorted array, assuming the smaller array is a subsequence of the larger array:

```py
def aligned(small, large, fillvalue):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(small) and j < len(large):
        assert(large[j] <= small[i])
        if large[j] < small[i]:
             yield fillvalue
             j += 1
        else:
             yield small[i]
             i += 1
             j += 1
    for _ in range(len(large) - j):
        yield fillvalue

print(list( aligned([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19], range(25), -1) ))
# [-1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -1, 7, -1, -1, -1, 11, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, 17, -1, 19, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

print(list( aligned(
    [-89, -9, -3, 3, 53],
    [-89, -88, -10, -9, -8, -3, 3, 50, 51, 52, 53], 0)
))
#   [-89,   0,   0, -9,  0, -3, 3,  0,  0,  0, 53]
```